# MessageDigest in Rust

Tags: java, encoding, rust, digest

I'm not really that strong in cryptography, so I'm striving to understand what this Java code exactly does:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
md.update("some string".getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```

**and** **convert** it to Rust.

So how can I do the same thing in Rust, what traits should I use? Is it http://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/util/sha2/struct.Sha256.html or something else?

Comment: are you found a solution about this issue? I want to do the same thing.@Incerteza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rustc::util::sha2::Sha256` is part of the Rust compiler and is not meant for external use. You should use the [rust-crypto](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto) crate instead. Its `sha2` module implements SHA-256.

Comment: how do I create a MessageDigest and get "digest" part of it?